# How to read a float from binary WebM file?

Tags: php, binary, webm

I'm trying to learn binary and create a simple WebM parser in PHP based on [Matroska](https://matroska.org/technical/specs/rfc/index.html).

I read TimecodeScale, MuxingAppm WritingApp, etc. with `unpack(format, data)`. My problem is when I reach `Duration` (0x4489) in `Segment Information` (0x1549a966) I must read a `float` and based on `TimecodeScale` convert it to seconds: 261.564s->00:04:21.564 and I don't know how.

This is a sample sequence:

```
`2A D7 B1 83 0F 42 40 4D 80 86 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 57 41 86 67 6F 6F 67 6C 65 44 89 88 41 0F ED E0 00 00 00 00 16 54 AE 6B`

TimecodeScale := 2ad7b1 uint [ def:1000000; ]

MuxingApp := 4d80 string; ("google")

WritingApp := 5741 string; ("google")

Duration := 4489 float [ range:>0.0; ]

Tracks := 1654ae6b container [ card:*; ]{...}
```

I must read a float after (0x4489) and return 261.564s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duration is a double precision floating point value (64-bits) represented in the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) format. If you want to see how the conversion is done check [this](https://gregstoll.dyndns.org/~gregstoll/floattohex/).

The `TimecodeScale` is the timestamp scale in nanoseconds.

In `php` you can do:

```php
$bin = hex2bin('410fede000000000');
$timecode_scale = 1e6;

// endianness
if (unpack('S', "\xff\x00")[1] === 0xff) {
    $bytes = unpack('C8', $bin);
    $bytes = array_reverse($bytes);
    $bin = implode('', array_map('chr', $bytes));
}

$duration = unpack('d', $bin)[1];
$duration_s = $duration * $timecode_scale / 1e9;

echo "duration=${duration_s}s\n";
```

Result:

```
duration=261.564s
```

Comment: Thx @aergistal, that's exactly what i needed, you saved my day (i learned many things from you)